# Contour integral $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{2z^2+z}{z^2-1}\, dz$ using residues

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to evaluate the contour integral

$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{2z^2+z}{z^2-1}\, dz.$$ In this case the two singular
points lie on the boundary (on the contour). So do I count the residues at this points or do I ignore them ?

Comment: In this region you have two singularities so using residue theorem you count both of them.

Comment: Obviously it is recommendable to avoid such complications, by choosing a different contour. For example a circle with radius 2.

Comment: You need to evaluate the Cauchy Principal Value. The contribution from a pole on the boundary is half of that of an interior pole.

Answer (score 1):

As @user_of_math stated, poles on the contours only contribute half; that is,
$$
\oint_{\lvert z\rvert = 1}\frac{2z^2+z}{z^2-1}dz = 2\pi i\sum_{<\partial R}\text{Res} + \pi i\sum_{\partial R}\text{Res}
$$
where $\partial R$ is the contour. So $<\partial R$ is inside the contour and $\partial R$ is on the contour. Since we have no poles in the contour, the first sum is zero.
\begin{align}
\pi i\sum_{\partial R}\text{Res} & = \pi i\biggl[\lim_{z\to -1}(z+1)\frac{2z^2+z}{z^2-1}+\lim_{z\to 1}(z-1)\frac{2z^2+z}{z^2-1}\biggr]\\
&=\pi i
\end{align}